# Mock an axios call in a vue method using Jest

Tags: javascript, html, unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs

I have looked for a solution to this but other questions dont really match my use case.
I have a function in a Vue file:

```
getStatus () {
      const statusRetriveKey = 0
      // Sets parameters from external file
      const url = serverDetails.url
      const params = { ...serverDetails.params }
      axios
        .get(`${url}admin/${statusRetriveKey}`, {
          params
        })
        .then((response) => {
          this.systemStatus = response.data[0].systemStatus
          this.alert = response.data[0].alert
          this.awayMessage = response.data[0].awayMessage
        })
        // Catch and display errors
        .catch((error) => {
          this.error = error.toString()
          console.log('Error on check System status: ' + error)
        })
    },
```

I am trying to write a unit test in Jest that will check that the data variables; systemStatus,alert and awayMessage are set correctly if that is what is returned by the GET request.

So far I have the following:

```
    it("Should call axios and return data", async () => {
        mockAxios.get.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve({
            data:{
                systemStatus: true,
                //the other variables
              }
        }))
        const response = await wrapper.vm.getStatus();
        console.log(response)
        expect(wrapper.vm.$data.systemStatus).toBe(true)
        expect(mockAxios.get).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    })
```

However I am receiving for the system status variable:

```
expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality
    Expected: true
    Received: null
```

I know that the mock is not feeding data into the method but not sure on how to resolve. Is it because I am not explicitly returning from the method in the vue file and rather using *this* to set the data values?

---

Solution:

```
// Import dependencies
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import axios from 'axios'
// Import component
import Page from 'path'

jest.spyOn(axios, "get").mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve({ data: [{ systemStatus: false, ...:..., ...:... }] }));


// Set Model data
const models = {
  ...
  }
}
describe('Page', () => {
  let wrapper
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallowMount(Page, {
      propsData: {
        model: models
      },
    })
  })
  it("Should call axios and return data", async () => {
    await wrapper.vm.getStatus();
    expect(wrapper.vm.$data.systemStatus).toBe(false)
    expect(wrapper.vm.$data....).toBe('...')
    expect(wrapper.vm.$data....).toBe('...')
  },)
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So not sure what is mockAxios here, is it some npm module?

One way you could do it is using [spyOn](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname)

```
import axios from 'axios';

jest.spyOn(axios, "get").mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve({data: {/* Here you can add your data */}));
```

So in your test, notice [mockImplementationOnce](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockimplementationoncefn).
It will be mocked only for one call

```
    it("Should call axios and return data", async () => {
        await wrapper.vm.getStatus();
    })
```

Edit:

On the line where you log response you will always get undefined because you do not have return statement in the function getStatus.

Comment: Thanks, that seems closer. Now my test is calling the function inside the vue file but the values that are being set for the data variables are the one coming from the _actual_ GET request, rather than the ones set in the jest.spyOn line?

Comment: For this test data variables should not be coming from actual GET, everything you pass in `Promise.resolve` should be consider as a response from your GET request.

Comment: Yes but rather than getting the values from `Promise.resolve`, the test file is pulling from the actual GET for some reason

Comment: hm.. well in this example we used mockImplementationOnce, and it will do just that mock once. Are you by any chance sending more then one GET request? If that is the case `jest.spyOn..` in side of that test should help

Comment: After some more fiddling around with it I got it to work. Thanks a million, solution added to the question